# SQL Query that sorts information into two new columns based on a third column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that stores basic site information, another one that stores the site address, and a third table for the phone. My phone table contains phone numbers, and the type of number.

What I want to do is get my site information, and the main contact number and fax number. So far, my statement looks like this:

```
SELECT site.isiteid,
    site.iclientid,
    csitecode, 
    csitename,
    binactive,
    caddress1,
    caddress2,
    ccity,
    cstateid,
    czip,
    icountryid,
    cattention,
    cemail,
    cnumber,
    cextension
FROM dbo.site 
    INNER JOIN dbo.address
        ON dbo.site.isiteid = dbo.address.isiteid
            AND (site.isiteid = 2)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.phone
        ON dbo.site.isiteid = dbo.phone.isiteid
            AND (dbo.phone.iphtypeid = 1)
```

This gets me all of the information that I need except for the fax number (dbo.phone.iphtypeid=3). Is there a way to add another column to the result called [fax], and populate it when site.isiteid=phone.isiteid AND phone.iphtypeid=3? Thus, the last 4 columns returned would be `[cemail][cnumber][cextension][cfax].`

**RESOLVED**

Thank you to all three who answered. All the answers were similar, so I selected the one that had the most detailed explanation. I did need to add the table name to both cnumber references and cextension to avoid ambiguity. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by adding another join to `dbo.phone`.  To distinguish between the two uses, you will need to give the second join an alias.  So, something like:

```
SELECT site.isiteid,
    site.iclientid,
    csitecode, 
    csitename,
    binactive,
    caddress1,
    caddress2,
    ccity,
    cstateid,
    czip,
    icountryid,
    cattention,
    cemail,
    phone.cnumber,
    phone.cextension,
    phone_fax.cnumber AS cfax
FROM dbo.site 
    INNER JOIN dbo.address
        ON dbo.site.isiteid = dbo.address.isiteid
            AND (site.isiteid = 2)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.phone
        ON dbo.site.isiteid = dbo.phone.isiteid
            AND (dbo.phone.iphtypeid = 1)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.phone AS phone_fax
        ON dbo.site.isiteid = phone_fax.isiteid
            AND (phone_fax.iphtypeid = 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another `JOIN` clause

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.phone f
ON dbo.site.isiteid = f.isiteid
AND f.iphtypeid = 3
```

You would then add f.cfax to the `SELECT` list.

It might also be good to give the other tables aliases so you can distinguish which columns are coming from which tables.

Comment: Don't you also need to use the `f` alias in the ON clause?

Comment: Aliases phone as F ignores alias... I'm not sure () is necessary either.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like, even though I'm not sure of how you're tables are defined.

```
SELECT site.isiteid,
    site.iclientid,
    csitecode, 
    csitename,
    binactive,
    caddress1,
    caddress2,
    ccity,
    cstateid,
    czip,
    icountryid,
    cattention,
    cemail,
    cnumber,
    cextension,
    CASE WHEN C.iphtypeid = 3 THEN C.cnumber ELSE NULL END [cfax]
FROM dbo.site A
    INNER JOIN dbo.address 
        ON dbo.site.isiteid = dbo.address.isiteid
            AND (site.isiteid = 2)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.phone C
        ON A.isiteid = C.isiteid
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  I expect the requirement is that the main phone number (type 1) is needed in `cnumber` and that the fax number is needed in `cfax`.  This will end up returning multiple rows for each phone type.  I see what you're trying to do by joining only once -- the only way I know how to do that is to pivot, and that might be a bit overkill.